# Prompt error message if user choose 1 before 2 in a menu in C

Tags: c, if-statement, menu

I have a code written in C where I need the user to choose between 4 different choices in a menu.
My code looks like this:

```
while(t!=0)
{
printf("-------------------MENU---------------------------\n");
printf("1. Randomize array.\n");
printf("2. Sort array in ascending order.\n");
printf("3. Print min- and max value.\n");
printf("4. Search for a number in the array.\n");
scanf("%d",&t);
    switch(t)
    {
        case 1:
        randomize(array);
        print(array);
        break;

        case 2:
        array[ARRAYSIZE]=bubblesort(array,ARRAYSIZE);
        break;

        case 3:
        array[ARRAYSIZE]=max(array,ARRAYSIZE);
        break;

        case 4:
        search(array,ARRAYSIZE);
        break;

        default:
        printf("Wrong input. Please try again!");
    }   
}
```

I want the user to choose 1 before 2,3 and 4. I've tried using a if-statement in a while-loop like this:

```
while(t!=1)
{
if(!array[ARRAYSIZE])
{
 printf("You must choose 1 first!");
}
}
```

But even then if I choose 1 first the I still get error message 'You must choose 1 first', i guess the if-statement still reads the array[ARRAYSIZE] as empty?

I was thinking of perhaps returning some sort of boolean flag from the function randomize() which tells an if-statement in main() if choice 1 has been executed.
I'm really stuck here. Do anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the definition, but `array[ARRAYSIZE]` may be out of range and you mustn't access there if it is out of range.

Comment: At least `array[ARRAYSIZE]` is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: So you want the user to start off with a randomized array? Why not do that by calling `randomize()` before entering the menu? The menu option would then to re-randomize the array.

Comment: How will your program work if user press instead **1**, let's say **a** or **s** or **d** ? You should make sure that your program does accept only that number if not, well you will have some crocodiles in there.

Answer (score 1):

A example of simple implementation for the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int one_is_chosen = 0;
    int t = 1;
    while(t!=0)
    {
        printf("menu\n");
        if(scanf("%d",&t)!=1)break;
        if(!one_is_chosen && (t==2 || t==3 || t==4))
        {
            puts("You have to choose 1 before choosing 2, 3 or 4.");
        }
        else
        {
            switch(t)
            {
                case 1:
                    one_is_chosen = 1;
                    puts("one");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    puts("two");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    puts("three");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    puts("four");
                    break;
                default:
                    puts("wrong input");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not good because the user may input `0`, which means to break from the loop, and @Acolla says "I want the user to choose 1 before 2,3 and 4." and he/she doesn't say that he/she wants the user to choose 1 before 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the whole array, you might want to have a flag saying if the array have been initialized or not.

Maybe something like this:

```
int initialized = 0;  // Start out as "false"

switch (t)
{
case 1:
    // Initialize array...
    initialized = 1;
    break;

case 2:
    if (!initialized)
    {
        printf("You need to initialize your array by selecting alternative 1 first.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do the actual stuff here...
    }
    break;

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!
I got i working by using a flag and if-statement within the case.